# Add a blank page and menu item

Tags: windows-template-studio

I've developed a working app using the Windows Template Studio.

I need to go back and add a Blank Page.  I've used the Navigation Pane (Hamburger Menu) so I want it added to the menu as well.

I've tried, but can only add the Page as a new item in the Views folder.

Is there a way to "re-open" the Windows Template Studio "Designer"  and add new features to the app?

Answer (score 3):

In the Solution Explorer tab, right click the Project (not the current solution) that you want to modify. About halfway down the menu you will see a selection for "Windows Template Studio". There you can choose to add a New Page or a New Feature.